# Is there an iOS PDF reader with support for PDF layers?

Tags: applications, ios, pdf

I was looking for a PDF Reader application which supported PDF layers (turning them on and off).

Do any exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [DocuWorks viewer](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=412415307&mt=8) will, but does not seem to be available in the U.S. store right now for some reason.

Comment: Who makes it? Can you provide a URL to a website for the product? (The iTunes link doesn't work for me)

Comment: http://www.fxap.com.sg/product/productDescription.jsp?id=167